# How to compare and MERGE two SQL Server environments (not just databases)

Tags: sql-server, sqlcompare

Many similar questions were asked before, and mostly about comparing database schemas and data. That's all fine, but what about all the other SQL Server objects in the system overall?

This is the closest [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19924/how-to-compare-two-sql-server-2008-configurations) I've found, but it doesn't answer my query on a tool to be able to also create an SQL script of the variances, that can be easily applied to another server - including new user logins, roles, schemas, linked-servers, maps, maintenance plans, etc.

The other tool I found that does this is TOAD for SQL Server, but it's not cheap. I was hoping for an SQL script solution? Particularly with a mix of SQL Server environments from 2008 R2 to 2017?

Thanks

Comment: There are some 3rd party tools like [ApexSQL Diff and DataDiff](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-diff.aspx) or [RedGate SQL compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/?utm_source=bing&utm_term=%2Bsql%20%2Btools&utm_campaign&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=%7cpcrid%7c77034636709275%7cpkw%7c%2Bsql%20%2Btools%7cpmt%7cbb%7cpdv%7cc%7c&msclkid=e200f9a4c93c155a7003a7b0555f3345&gclid=CKie6vvf8eYCFcjCGwod7awO5w&gclsrc=ds) that could help.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [dbatools](http://dbatools.io/)? It is a free, community-maintained PowerShell module that provides an extensive range of migration-based cmdlets to migrate whole instances from one instance/server to another (among many other things the module can do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HandyD, [dbaTools](https://dbatools.io/) does this and more! Cheers